# Mono Repo: Accessing typescript file outside of project gives 'pos' undefined error

Tags: angular, typescript, monorepo

I am trying to build an Angular mono repo. However, when I try to `run lerna run start --scope=@demo/core-app` I get the following error:

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'pos' of undefined
    at createFileDiagnosticAtReference (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:107529:68)
    at addProgramDiagnosticAtRefPath (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:107547:93)
    at checkSourceFilesBelongToPath (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:107208:25)
    at Object.getCommonSourceDirectory (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:105619:21)
    at Object.getDeclarationEmitOutputFilePath (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:17179:125)
    at getOutputPathsFor (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:99488:112)
    at forEachEmittedFile (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:99425:41)
    at Object.emitFiles (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:99654:9)
    at emitWorker (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:106125:33)
    at E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:106102:72
    at runWithCancellationToken (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:106205:24)
    at Object.emit (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:106102:26)
    at getFileEmitOutput (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:108003:26)
    at updateShapeSignature (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:108239:36)
    at getFilesAffectedByUpdatedShapeWhenModuleEmit (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:108442:46)
    at Object.getFilesAffectedBy (E:\Temp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:108194:144)
```

**Here's how the folder is structured with Lerna:** (Example github repo - **[Link](https://github.com/shyamal890/mono-demo)**)

```
-- packages
   -- core-app (Angular project)
   -- shared (Shared project from where the angular project would utilize some types)
```

**Root Level tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {     
      "baseUrl": "./",      /* Enable incremental compilation */
      "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
      "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015',
      "strict": false,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
      // "esModuleInterop": true,                  
      "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    },
    "references": [
      { "path": "packages/shared" },
      { "path": "packages/core-app" }
    ]
  }
```

**Shared project tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "outDir": "lib",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "downlevelIteration": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "module": "es2020",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "importHelpers": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "declarationMap": true,
      "lib": [
        "es2018",
        "dom"
      ],
      "composite": true,
      "paths": {
        "@demo/core-app/*": ["../core-app/src/*"],
        "@demo/shared/*": ["./src/*"]
      }
    },
    "references": [
      { "path": "../core-app" } 
    ]  
  }
```

**Core-app (Angular) tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "composite": true,
    "paths": {
      "@demo/core-app/*": ["src/*"],
      "@demo/shared/*": ["../shared/src/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "../shared" } 
  ]  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to add references and paths in `tsconfig.json` on both side, lerna should be able to do it for you after bootstrapping.

**1. remove `references`, `paths` and `composite` in tsconfig.json**

After you remove references and paths, you should be able to see a different error indicating the missing `@demo/shared/models/ExampleModel` module.

**2. move the `models` folder in shared module**

To have the exact path of @demo/shared/models/ExampleModel, move the `models` folder to the root level of shared module and remove `src` folder.

**3. use interface or type for type definition. Otherwise, you will hit "Strict Class Initialization" error**

*shared/models/ExampleModel.ts*

```
export interface ExampleModel{
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
}
```

<del>**4. add index.ts to export type for future expandability**</del>

<del>*shared/models/index.ts*</del>

<del>export * from './ExampleModel'</del>

<del>**5. expose a entry point in shared module**</del>

<del>In `package.json`, add main entry point</del>

<del>*shared/package.json*</del>

<del>{
    "name": "@demo/shared",
    ...
    "main": "models/index.ts"
}</del>

**6. add dev and peer dependencies of `@demo/shared` packages in `core-app`**

*core-app/package.json*

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@demo/shared": "^0.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    @demo/shared": "^0.0.1",
    ...
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
}
```

> typescript should be below 4.2.0 for angular 11

**7. fixing typo in `app.component.html`**

*should be examples instead of exmaples**

```
<div *ngFor="let example of examples"> 
  {{example.Name}}
</div>
```

**8. boostraping**

```
npx lerna bootstrap --hoist
```

- More on [hoist](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/main/doc/hoist.md)

**9. run the app**

```
npx lerna run start --scope=@demo/core-app
```

---

Here is the [working rep](https://github.com/michael-vascue/test-ng-mono)o for your reference. You can read the last commmit for details, it is concluded in the above steps.

Comment: That does solve the issue @Mic but is this possible without exporting all the typescript files through `index.ts`?

I would like to avoid it as when the `models` grow it would be very difficult to make sure we don't mix out on adding any files in `index.ts`

Comment: I don't get it. 1st, you need to have a overall entry point and 2nd, you can have central point of control of all the type definitions, you can avoid name conflict as well. If you have multiple model with the same name, it should be better wrap it in namespace or rename it when exporting. You can have a modular setting, so the index.ts don't get overwhelmed. update the code and you can see in the github.

Comment: actually, you can think of the type definitions in angular way where app.module.ts is the central point of control of importing all other modules while A modules can import B modules without directly importing it in app.module.ts `app.module -> A.module -> B.module`, such like a tree system. So your type can be `index.ts -> A.index -> B.index`. If you follow this pattern, I don't see any disadvantages of using index.ts you stated in the comment.

Comment: I get your point. However, my thinking is that I would like developers to avoid one more step of adding the types they create to the index.ts as its an unnecessary extra step. 

Imagine we have 2 angular projects. It may happen that service from project 1 may be referred to by project 2. In this case, simply importing the file instead of adding it to index.ts would be much more faster and simple isn't it?

Comment: i see what you mean, you can simply remove main in package.json and all index.ts, it will do the trick. updated github for your reference.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh have you tried the solution? I think it should be what you want

Comment: Thank you so much @Mic that solves my question. :)

Comment: Hi @Mic I tried this in my production app and suddenly realized this solution is not working. Modified the github repo - https://github.com/shyamal890/mono-demo as an example project with Enum which fails

Comment: will take a look but may not be able to reply you today.

Comment: I just read your code, you are using named import but your enum export is using default. try to add `const` in front of enum - `export const enum ExampleEnum { Enum1,  Enum2 }`.  I also added enum in my example repo: https://github.com/michael-vascue/test-ng-mono Hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks that does solve the issue. I then encountered another one. When accessing some models I get the [model] is not a constructor error. I am exporting the class as in the github repo.

Comment: Are you exporting class in the models ? in the answer, I stated that if you use class, you will hit "Strict Class Initialization" error. You may need to tune the tsconfig config to bypass the error. And It is more natural to use `type` or `interface` for type defintion in a library as it should not have any/pretend to have implementation.

Comment: If you really want to export class, in your root or core-app tsconfig.json adding `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` to compilerOptions will help you get rid of the error

Comment: Actually I don't think that's the issue, as I defined the variable as nullable like `Name?: string`

Comment: optional field so there is nothing to initialise